# Large PHP project. Debugging with eclipse PDT, xdebug on WAMP

Tags: php, ajax, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

We have a very large enterprise Web application developed using Mojave (MVC) framework in PHP.
Continuous development is still going on. There is an extensive use of AJAX throughout the system.
Debugging an issue is a nightmare currently.

I am wondering if this environment would help in debugging. Or are there any better tools?

Local Development environment:
WAMP
Windows 64
Eclipse PDT with XDebug (Recently installed)
MySQL.

Can we debug Ajax-heavy PHP web applications using XDebug?
Can I setup this project in Eclipse? (Import? Or just open the webroot of the application?)?
Are there any other better tools?

Comment: Yes, you can. Any particular question? [google is your friend](http://www.google.co.nz/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=eclipse+xdebug)

Comment: debug your javascript in your browser's console

Comment: Most of what you've mentioned are debugging tools (They are meant to help you track down the reason why your code doesn't work).  You need testing tools (to test whether the code works as it should) such as PHPUnit for unit testing and Selenium for use case testing.

Comment: Thanks all. Will I be able to step through AJAX calls as well with XDebug or it skips all JS stuff and steps through only PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xdebug doesn't support javascript itself, but you can use the browser extensions (that I've just pointed to in your other question) to start a debugging session when you want it (ie, an ajax-ui action): http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser-extensions

cheers,
Derick